# what are these two things in my basement and can they be used to add a bathroom

Tags: plumbing

I am not a technical person and I am wondering what are these two things in my basement?

- I think one of them is the water input (with meter) for my house
- the second one coming from the ground is for the wastewater output

I am wondering can they be used to add a full bathroom in my basement? the reason I am asking is I contacted a contractor on the phone and he gave me two prices based on whether he needs to dig the concrete foundation to connect the wastewater.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's really hard to tell - is the clean-out (the thing on the floor) recessed several inches down, or is the carpet just cut oddly there?

Comment: It's not recessed. It's protruding at a 45 degree angle away from the wall. My guess is that the sewer exits the basement perpendicular there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One is a water meter on your main supply that can be read remotely.

The other looks like a drain access plug in case you ever need to run a snake down the pipe.

Comment: "drain access plug" is also called a clean-out.

Comment: Right, and neither are facilities for a future bathroom. Both must be maintained more or less as they are.